# Is there any way to distribute the processes of the system on all cores in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, cpu-usage, task-manager

My computer is running all processes on CPU0. I don't know how to change that behavior. The processor is from the 3rd generation and there are no updates from the vendor (VAIO) to the software.

I think that is why Windows execute all the process in cpu0 as default. Probably run process in all cores could reduce time on execution.

Is there any way to distribute the processes of the system on all cores in windows 10?

---

Task manager picture with all processes in cpu0:

[image: task manager' picture with all processes in cpu0]

Processes running after I restart win10:

[image: processes running after I restart win10]

Comment: This strongly depends on *what* processes you are running. Some software is designed to use multiple cores, some is not. What is the issue you are running into? Are there any slowdowns?

Comment: Yes.. There is an increment in the processor's heat.
After the computer start, the cpu0 is already running at 100% and it not change.

Comment: But what's the problem of processor's heat? That's why there are fans, to cool the processors. In other words: what's the real world problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find under the "Details" tab in task manager that the bulk of that CPU usage is a single process, and that process isn't particularly multithreaded.

A proces is an application, and a process can have multiple threads, though it doesn't have to (depends on how it was written). Windows can freely move threads across CPU cores, but if a process has only a single thread, then there is no way to spread that across you CPU cores.

Some processes may still be multithreaded, but have the bulk of their work occur on a single thread, meaning you still run into the situation where one of your CPU cores is doing all the work.

Comment: I watched the details tab as you mentioned. Almost every process is running on cpu00 (processes like svchost.exe conhost.exe and programs that I started like teams, firefox). When I check the processor affinity, it has <all processors> enable. But still almost every process runs in cpu00.

Comment: How do you know they are using only the first core?

From your screenshot the other cores do have usage, albiet low. Is there just one or two processes dominating the usage if you go into Details and sort by CPU?

What problem are you trying to solve here?